# How to plot irregular latitude and longitude in xarray?

Tags: plot, nan, latitude-longitude, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file with daily data for a month. In this file, there are `irregular latitude and longitude` points data. I want to create a plot of `time[0]` or any time of this data, but the result seems incorrect. How can I show the plot with `nan-space`?

**data file**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll35zh4k5ws7nnh/day1.nc?dl=0

**Code**

```
import xarray as xr
month_daily1 = xr.open_dataset('/Daily_Month/1/day1.nc')
month_daily1

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                 (Lat: 175, Lon: 200, time: 31)
Coordinates:
  * time                    (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 ... 2018-01-31
  * Lat                     (Lat) float64 29.92 29.93 29.94 ... 33.0 33.01 33.02
  * Lon                     (Lon) float64 47.61 47.62 47.63 ... 50.5 50.51 50.52
Data variables:
    Alt                     (time, Lat, Lon) float64 ...
    Temperature             (time, Lat, Lon) float64 ...
    Relative Humidity       (time, Lat, Lon) float64 ...
    Wind speed              (time, Lat, Lon) float64 ...
    Wind direction          (time, Lat, Lon) float64 ...
    Short-wave irradiation  (time, Lat, Lon) float64 ...


# convert kelvin to celsius
data_nonnull = month_daily1.dropna(dim ='time', how='all')
air = data_nonnull.Temperature - 273.15
air


<xarray.DataArray 'Temperature' (time: 31, Lat: 175, Lon: 200)>
array([[[nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
      ...,

       [[nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],

       [[nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],

Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 ... 2018-01-31
  * Lat      (Lat) float64 29.92 29.93 29.94 29.95 ... 32.99 33.0 33.01 33.02
  * Lon      (Lon) float64 47.61 47.62 47.63 47.64 ... 50.41 50.5 50.51 50.52


%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
air2d = air.isel(time= 0)
air2d.plot.pcolormesh('Lon', 'Lat');
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: perhaps the xemsf package can help you: https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that good with XArray, therefore suggest solution with module netCDF4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('tkagg')
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# =======================================================
from netCDF4 import Dataset
ncin=Dataset('day1.nc');
tempin=ncin.variables['Temperature'][0,:,:]- 273.15;
lonin=ncin.variables['Lon'][:];
latin=ncin.variables['Lat'][:];
ncin.close()
# -------------------------------------------------------
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np
kk=np.where(np.isnan(np.array(tempin).flatten())==False)
lonm,latm=np.meshgrid(lonin,latin);
tinterp=griddata((lonm.flatten()[kk],latm.flatten()[kk]),tempin.flatten()[kk],(lonm,latm));

ax = plt.subplot(121,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lonin,latin,tempin);
ax = plt.subplot(122,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lonin,latin,tinterp);
plt.show()
```

Final results looks like this: on the left is the original and right the interpolated (nan dropped figure).
[image]

I can propose an answer, where I combine the XArray and the Scipy griddata as the `interpolate_na` is not working very nice (look at the part and the result with `filled_a`, `filled_b`) for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('tkagg')
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# =======================================================
month_daily1 = xr.open_dataset('day1.nc')

# convert kelvin to celsius
data_nonnull = month_daily1.dropna(dim ='time', how='all')
air = data_nonnull.Temperature - 273.15
air2d = air.isel(time= 0)
# =======================================================
ax = plt.subplot(121,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
air2d.plot.pcolormesh('Lon', 'Lat');
ax = plt.subplot(122,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
filled_a=air2d.interpolate_na(dim='Lat');
filled_b=filled_a.interpolate_na(dim='Lon');
filled_c=filled_b.interpolate_na(dim='Lat');
filled_c.plot.pcolormesh('Lon', 'Lat');
plt.show()
# =======================================================
tempin=air2d.values[:];
lonin=air2d.Lon
latin=air2d.Lat
# -------------------------------------------------------
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np
kk=np.where(np.isnan(np.array(tempin).flatten())==False)
lonm,latm=np.meshgrid(lonin,latin);
tinterp=griddata((lonm.flatten()[kk],latm.flatten()[kk]),tempin.flatten()[kk],(lonm,latm));

ax = plt.subplot(121,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lonin,latin,tempin);
ax = plt.subplot(122,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lonin,latin,tinterp);
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi @msi_gerva, Thanks for your reply, It's great job, but it is important for me do it with xarray.

Comment: @nickan, you can try to combine the `XArray` and `Scipy` `griddata`, basically as I am doing with the added code. Perhaps somebody more experienced can show the proper way with `XArray`.

Comment: @ msi_gerva, Thanks for your suggestion.